# Heat equation: proving that smaller diffusion leads to bigger solution via energy methods

Tags: sobolev-spaces, heat-equation, parabolic-pde, bochner-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain and denote by $u_\alpha$ the solution of the heat equation
$$u_t -\alpha \Delta u = f$$
with $f \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$, $u(0) = u_0$ given and $u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$.

We have
$$u_\alpha \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega)) \cap H^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega)).$$
If the diffusion constant gets smaller, then the solution should get bigger (in the sense that $u_\alpha(t) \geq u_\beta(t)$ for a.e. $t \in (0,T)$ whenever $\alpha \leq \beta$). How can I show this via energy methods or without using further regularity of the solution?

Comment: What's your intuition on "getting bigger"? If we designed $f$ adapted to certain fixed $\alpha$ and $u_0$, we could drive $u$ to $0$ at a fixed finite time $T>0$ and stay as zero solution afterward for some $\alpha=\alpha_0>0$ but not for smaller $\alpha$.

Comment: I thought (at least for $f=0$), with the exponential formula for the solution on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Solving_the_heat_equation_using_Fourier_series), it should get bigger. Note their function $f$ is the initial data (here $u_0$).

Comment: For $f=0$ a standard argument would answer your question. For $f\neq 0$, I think your question needs extra clarification.

Comment: I don't see how the standard argument (which is testing the difference of the equations satisfied by $u_\alpha$ and $u_\beta$ with $(u_\alpha-u_\beta)^+$ works

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. Your question seems to be correct for any $f$ (obviously $f$ should not matter at all). First you'd already have observed that for sufficiently smooth solution $u$, your question boils down to maximum principle. Thus, we are done if we can regard $u$ with ony $H^1$-regularity a limit of smooth solution sequence, right? Since smooth data condition gives smooth solution, this is just well-posedness issue.

Comment: -or maybe you asked for a second different proof not relying on limiting argument, to get a different type of heuristic (if that be, you'd want to show maximum principle with only minimal number of regularity "directly", maybe expecting generalizability to variable coefficient setting with rough coefficients or such?)

Comment: Not sure I fully get you but what I mean is that it should be possible using the weak form and testing with something clever and manipulations to get the comparison (like I put now in the post). So yeah I want a different proof that doesn't rely on explicit representation of the solution if that makes sense?

Comment: Testing with $(u_\alpha-u_\beta)^+$ should work. Due to the regularity you wrote, this is a function in $L^2(H^1) \cap H^1(L^2)$. Of course you need to assume that $u_\alpha \ge0$. (The statement is wrong if $f\le0$ and $u_0\le0$)